# ROS Answers SE migration: Mapping SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, 2d-mapping, gmapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I want to build a map with my robot that uses wheel odometry and a laserscanner and I also want to use the Navigation Stack. I already made a map with the map_server gmapping. But actually I want that my robot is building the map the same time it is driving around. So that I can navigate my robot while it is mapping. And I also want to give that map to the Navigation Stack. Can I also use gmapping for that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206320/mapping-slam/) by [hannjaminbutton](https://answers.ros.org/users/22033/hannjaminbutton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle yes. You only have to consider that the map changes and the robot pose in the map might also change as it is built online.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0